# Convert DateTime to another DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime

Can someone explain to me what is going on here?

```
<?php 
$date= \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", "17:30:23"); 
var_dump($date); 
$date = new DateTime('@' . $date->format('U'));
var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) { 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-09-06 17:30:23" 
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
    ["timezone"]=> string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam" 
} 

object(DateTime)#2 (3) { 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-09-06 15:30:23" 
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) 
    ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" 
}
```

How can I transfer the time from one DateTime to another, so it is exactly the same?
I ask because I have my own Date class which extends `\DateTime` which I need to use, but my source is a regular `\DateTime` object.

In action: http://3v4l.org/uEQES#v530

Comment: *"I ask because I have my own Date class which extends \DateTime"* - You should show it then. Plus, in doing that, may have some unexpected/adverse effects.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. Just has a `__toString()` method. And that doesn't matter anyway, the example above uses the standard `\DateTime` class and the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your DateTime objects to be in the same timezone. In this case I used UTC, since Unix Timestamps are always in UTC:

```
$date= \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", "17:30:23"); 
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($date); 
$date = new DateTime('@' . $date->format('U'));
var_dump($date);
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/RHiHq)

If you want to get back to your timezone use:

```
$date= \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", "17:30:23"); 
var_dump($date); 
$date = new DateTime('@' . $date->format('U'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
var_dump($date);
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/7r8t1)

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense now!